# Using chemfig arrows between tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I want to use [`chemfig` arrows](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Chemfig_Arrow_Examples.png) between two tikz nodes.

I looked up chemfig manual. It has examples where chemfig scheme is drawn in tikz node, but no example of how to use chemfig arrows as tikz arrow. I could use it to draw an arrow between node (a) and (b):

```
 \draw[] (a) -- node[] {\schemestart \arrow{<->} \schemestop } (b);
```

If I was less lazy, I would write a macro. I was wondering if chemfig already have such macros (or pgfkeys based solutions) such that its arrows can be used at tikz arrows as if they were tikz arrows? e.g.

```
 \draw[-some chemfig arrow-,draw] (a) -- (b);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chemfig`'s arrow tips are TikZ arrow tips called `CF`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-CF] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\schemestart
  A \arrow B
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to use `\arrow{<=>}` ? I tried putting the `\draw[\arrow{<=>}]` etc. but I ran into `undefined control sequence`.

Comment: @Dilawar I don't think you can… `\draw[\schemestart{}\arrow{<=>}\schemestop]` might work but might need adjusting with the `compoundsep` parameter.